# Is it possible to activate Windows Update after deactivated by system admin?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

On my windows xp machine, it seems like Windows Update is not active. When I try to start it, I get a message telling me that system admininstrator has deactivated it.

Is there some policy or register key to turn in on again. I have looked through security policy, but without success. I have admin access to the machine. Any chance on activating Windows Update again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this fixes the issue

http://www.dougknox.com/xp/scripts_desc/xp_winupd_netpolicy.htm

Comment: Glad your back in business.

Answer (score 1):

Logged in as administrator, run gpedit.msc

Check the settings under User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Compnents -> Windows Update

(this might be what you have already done)

Comment: HI Mikael, yes, the setting for configuration of automatic update is active (but all other options is not configured).

When I go to Windows Update in IE it still tells me that the service is deactivated. The same happens if I go to Control Panel and open the Windows Update dialog. Everything is grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326686) MS support document:

it's either caused by group policy, system policy or the registry. It also goes on to mention a fix that you may or may not have tried (the fix may not be applicable but the error message is the same). Try following the link and seeing if there's anything useful there.